# Piano arrangement identification from one measure of sheet music

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music, piano

On Music.SE, someone [posted a question about how to play a particular piano piece](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/48744/5693). The piece appears to be in 12/8 time and E-flat major, and looks *extremely* awkward to play. The author of the question mentions "the arranger", so I suspect the piece may not have originally been for solo piano, which might explain why the voicing is so awkward.

I've tried the sheet-music-search tool on IMSLP and another music-search tool I found via Google to no avail. I am dying of curiosity, because, frankly, I simply can't imagine why anyone would write what's written there, and yet it looks rather nicely engraved, and someone is making a legitimate effort to learn it.

Does anyone recognize this piece?

[image: awkward-piano]

I've tagged the question as "classical-music" because the piece at least appears to be emulating a classical idiom somewhat, but I'd actually be somewhat surprised if it's a "real" classical piece by a known composer, at least in its solo-piano form.

Comment: Why not ask the OP in music.SE? Music identification is a big no no in that forum as an end in itself, but I suppose knowing what piece is being talked about in a legit question would not offend the forum etiquette.

Comment: I'm wondering if music software such as Noteworthy was used to arrange the piece, as this can result in technically correct output, but which looks nothing like how it would usually be notated.

Comment: @joseem If you click on the link, you'll see that I did, and did not receive an answer.

Comment: @KyleStrand: Answer arrived in the mean time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP of the Music.SE submission provided an answer in the comments there, so I'll share it here to at least take this post off of the "unanswered questions" list:

The piece is an arrangement (by [Vika Yermolyeva](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Be-loLSUWT0)) of System of a Down's "Toxicity."